# How to get details of user who introduced violation in Sonar?

Tags: database, sonarqube

I am using sonar for capturing violations & to track who has introduced an error, we use SCM plugin.

I run sonar on nightly basis & my aim is to find out the details of the new violation introduced & who introduced it. Also, the violation which were solved.

How can i achieve it?

http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743298 
This WEB API will give me the file but not the detail about who introduced it, as i get this information from a plugin.

Is it possible to extract this information from Sonar database.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The "violations" Web Service currently does not return the information you're looking for because violations are not linked to developers. And there's a very good reason for that: the developer SCM login associated to a line where a violation has been detected is not necessarily the one who introduced this violation... So Sonar currently can't tell for sure who introduced a violation.

To answer your question, if you really want to get the SCM info about a file via the Web Service API, you should use the "resources" web service, not the "violations" one. For instance:

`http://my.sonar.server/api/resources?metrics=authors_by_line&resource=my-project-key:my-file-key`

But again, IMO, by correlating violations with basic SCM info, you're not doing things the right way.